# GCP deployment maanger template unable to create tagged firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to deploy a Linux VM with tag "http" and creating firewall for allowing HTTP Port 80 access as tagged firewall "http". The VM is getting deployed but no external access is working for the VM. Also gave startup script for VM but its not working

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: vm-test
  properties:
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script-url
        value: https://storage.googleapis.com/cf405bucket/install-web.sh
    zone: {{ properties["zone"] }}
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/zones/{{ properties["zone"] }}/machineTypes/n1-standard-2
    # For examples on how to use startup scripts on an instance, see:
    #   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript
    tags:
      items: ["http"]
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        diskName: disk-{{ env["deployment"] }}
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default
      # Access Config required to give the instance a public IP address
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
- type: compute.v1.firewall
  name: default-allow-http
  properties:
    sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default 
    targetTags: ["http"]
    allowed:
    - IPProtocol: TCP
      ports: ["80"]
```

Comment: Is your server listening on port 80? All we can see here is that you deployed an instance that you should be able to reach on port 80, not that you installed something that make your server listen on port 80 like nginx or apache.

Comment: Hi. I am trying to install apache using startup script in VM. That would be listening to port 80.

Comment: Are you sure it's working? To if the serveur is listening to 0.0.0.0:* log onto the server and do this command: netstat -tlupn

Comment: Post your startup script. Look at the Stackdriver logs for this instance and review the error messages. You can also look and the Compute Engine console output.

Comment: The start script is 
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
cat <<EOF > /var/www/html/index.html
<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>This page was created from a simple startup script!</p>
</body></html>
EOF
service apache2 start

Comment: Post your script formatted in your question. How can we detect errors from putting the script as a blob in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try SSH'ing into the deployment's created VM instance and run the command `apache2 --version`.

What happens? I assume you'll be told it isn't a recognised command or something...given it looks like the web server hasn't been installed for some reason. If so, perhaps try updating *install-web.sh* to include `sudo` before commands, i.e.,

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
```

Failing that, why not ditch the *install-web.sh* file altogether and just include the script in the config file directly (as there isn't much to it), e.g., something like:

```
    metadata:
     items:
     - key: startup-script
       value: |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y apache2
```